What does the condition $a^{4} - e^{4 i \varphi} \overline{a}^{4} = 0$ say about a unitary matrix with antidiagonal 0s?
Given a unitary matrix of the form
$$U = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & 0 \\ 
    0 & e^{i\varphi}\overline{a}
\end{bmatrix}$$, where $|a|=1$ and $\varphi\in\mathbb{R}$ ($\overline{a}$ is the complex conjugate of $a$).
I have the following condition:
$$a^{4} - e^{4 i \varphi} \overline{a}^{4} = 0$$
What does this condition say about $U$?
I see that if I fix $a$ I get certain solutions E.g.:
$$\begin{align}
a=\pm 1 \implies \varphi & = \frac{\pi n}{2} \\
a=\pm i \implies \varphi & = \pi n\qquad \text{or}\qquad \varphi = \pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
But I'm not sure what general statements I can make about $U$?

It implies $\bar{a}U$ is a fourth root of the identity matrix.
